# Config is deprecated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, bundler

I'm working on a new project and when I hit bundle install I got the following error:

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
 
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
extconf.rb:13:in `block in <main>': Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
extconf.rb:13:in `block in <main>': Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
 
make "DESTDIR="
Makefile:104: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

I've never seen this before, so I'm not sure how to fix it but it is certainly holding me up.

GemFILE

source :rubygems

```
gem "rails", "2.3.14"
gem "authlogic", "2.1.6"
gem "declarative_authorization", "0.5.1"
gem "carmen", "0.1.1"
gem "pg", "0.9.0"
gem "aws-s3", "0.6.2"
gem "paperclip", "2.3.3"
gem "taps", "0.3.8"
gem "vestal_versions", "1.0.2"
gem "formtastic", "1.0"
gem "validation_reflection", "0.3.8"
gem "factory_girl", "1.3.2"
gem "faker", "0.3.1"
gem 'prawn', :git => "git://github.com/sandal/prawn", :tag => '0.10.2', :submodules => true
#gem 'prawn', :git => "git://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn.git", :tag => '0.12.0', :submodules => true                                                            
gem "prawnto", "~> 0.0.4"
gem 'hoptoad_notifier', '>=2.4.4'
gem "whenever", "0.6.2", :require => false
gem 'whereuat'
gem 'RedCloth', '4.1.9'
gem 'heroku'
gem 'fastercsv'
gem 'will_paginate', '2.3.16'
gem "sunspot", '1.2.1'
gem 'sunspot_rails', '~> 1.2.1'
gem 'rake', '0.8.7'
gem 'rmagick', '2.13.1', :require => 'RMagick'
gem "chunky_png", '1.2.5'
gem "rqrcode", '0.4.2'
gem "pngqr", '0.6'
gem "acts_as_list", '0.1.4'
#gem 'docusign_rest'             

   
                                                                              |
group :development do                                                         |
  gem "mongrel", "1.1.5"                                                      |
  gem "ruby-debug", "0.10.3"                                                  |
  gem "pickler", "~> 0.2.0"                                                   |
  #gem 'sunspot_solr'                                                         |
end                                                                           |
                                                                              |
group :test, :cucumber do                                                     |
  #gem 'cucumber-rails',   '>=0.3.2'                                          |
  #gem 'cucumber', "0.10.7"                                                   |
  gem 'database_cleaner', '>=0.5.2', :require => false                        |
  gem 'rspec-rails',      '1.3.3', :require => false                          |
  gem 'rspec',            '1.3.1', :require => false                          |
  gem "webrat", "0.7.1"                                                       |
  #gem "email_spec", "0.6.2"                                                  |
  gem "launchy", "0.3.5"                                                      |
  #gem 'specjour', '0.5.0'                                                    |
end                                                                           |
                                                                              |
group :production do                                                          |
  gem "thin"                                                                  |
  gem 'newrelic_rpm'                                                          |
end                                                                           |
                                                                              |
                                                                              |
                                                                              |
                                                                              |
                                                                              |
```

Comment: From the error it looks like you've included an old gem in your bundler Gemfile which is using Config instead of RbConfig (which is deprecated in Ruby 2.0.0). Whats in your Gemfile?

Comment: Hi Greg Malcolm, thanks for pointing that out. I've added the Gemfile to the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is caused by `mongrel` which is not maintained for quite some time now. You can use `thin` in development as well as in production.

`ruby-debug` also won't work in 2.0. You can use [`pry`](https://github.com/pry/pry) or [`byebug`](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) as an alternative.

Comment: Thanks Mechanicalfish, i've updated the gem file with the full gem list. Please see if you find any other deprecated gems in the full list.

Comment: Nothing that I can see, it serms ok.

Comment: 'debugger' gem is also a good replacement for ruby-debug. It looks the same as ruby-debug, but it actually gets maintained.